# Let $g(x +2)+g(x-3) = 4x+8$. How can we find $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Let $g$ is a function and  $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and 
$$g(x +2)+g(x-3) = 4x+8$$

How can we find $g(x)$?

Comment: One such $g(x) =2x+5$

Comment: We see $g''(x+2)=-g''(x-3)$ so $g''$ is an odd function with period $T=5$. One of well-known case is $\sin''=\sin$ and we let $g(x)=k\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{5}x+\beta)+2x+5$. This function satisfies $g(x +2)+g(x-3) = 4x+8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest assumption is $g$ be linear. With $g(x)=ax+b$ we find $a=2$ and $b=5$.

Comment: How do we know there aren't nonlinear solutions?

Comment: Its better to start with $$g(x)=\sum_{r=0}^na_rx^r$$ and establish that $a_r=0$ for $r\ge2$

Comment: It's possible it has infinite solutions.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why can we assume that $g$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks. this assumption leads us to $r=2$ and then  $g(x)=ax+b$.